# Rails engine model inheritance from config

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a host app and engine. They should be independent and have its own models. However when I want to include the engine in my host app, I want an ability to inherit User from the host app.

So I did the following

```
module VotingApp
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace VotingApp

    config.user_model = VotingApp::ApplicationRecord
    config.user_model_path = nil
```

In initializers of host app

```
  require 'voting_app'

  VotingApp::Engine.config.user_model = ::User
  VotingApp::Engine.config.user_model_path = Rails.root.join('app/models/user.rb')
```

And finally in the engine's model.

```
module VotingApp
  class User < VotingApp::Engine.config.user_model
```

However this doesn't seem to work as `VotingApp::Engine.config.user_model` is only set to `::User` after the `VotingAp::User` has been loaded. Is there a way how to reload the class?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, after doing this, you then need to

1. Unload the current model in order to reload it
2. Reload the model

   ```
   VotingApp.send(:remove_const, :User)
   load "#{VotingApp::Engine.root}/app/models/voting_app/user.rb"
   ```

Then it all works as desired